# Connect to correct ad domain using User.Identity.Name?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I am using `User.Identity.Name` to get the user logged in with my web app.

Then I am querying AD to get properties for that user:

```
string[] sx = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
var username = sx[sx.Count() - 1];

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
searcher.Filter = string.Format(Filter, username);
SearchResult user = searcher.FindOne();
```

Now I want to add domain support:

```
string[] sx = UserIdentityName.Split('\\');
var username = sx[sx.Count() - 1];
var domain = sx[0];

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=" + domain));
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
searcher.Filter = string.Format(Filter, username);
SearchResult user = searcher.FindOne();
```

This does not work, perhaps because the domain is not fully qualified. So I have `DC=intra` where I would need `DC=intra,DC=contoso,DC=com`, and `DC=sub` where I would need `DC=sub,DC=intra,DC=contoso,DC=com`.

How can I still connect to the correct AD domain? Can I get full qualified username (UPN name) for user that is logged in, or can I get correct AD domain of user logged in, or how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work as you've discovered. Instead, bind based on the SID using something like this:

```
WindowsIdentity current = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;
DirectoryEntry userObject = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<SID=" + current.User.ToString() + ">");
```